# Unable to Add-Migration or Update-Database

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using the Microsoft Identity tables in my ASP application.  The `ApplicationDbContext` context which handles the Identity stuff is in my main `MyProject` project.  All of my other database stuff is in `MyContext` which is in the project `MyProject.Data`.

When I enabled migrations, the initial migration was created with all the Identity tables.  Then I ran `Enable-Migrations -ContextProjectName MyProject.Data -StartUpProjectName MyProject.Data -ContextTypeName MyProject.Data.MyContext -ProjectName MyProject -Force` so that I could have migrations created from my application tables in the `MyProject.Data` project.

Now when I try to `Add-Migration`, I get the error `Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201705262027077_InitialCreate]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.`

When I do `Update-Database` to apply any pending migrations (like the error message says), I get `Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.
You can use the Add-Migration command to write the pending model changes to a code-based migration.`

Now that error message is telling me to add a migration, which I can't do because the first error tells me to apply my migrations.  I don't want to enable automatic migrations.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you including the [ProjectName](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/entityframework/entity-framework-6-code-first-migrations-with-multiple-data-contexts) parameters on add-migration and update-database?

Comment: No, I wasn't.  I added that and it worked.  Thanks for the answer.